# Why do square brackets around __proto__ makes it enumerable in an object

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, prototype-chain

When using square brackets around `__proto__` in a object, `__proto__` is enumerable. When no square brackets are provided, `__proto__` is not enumerable.

Example:

```js
obj = {"__proto__": "Hello"}
for (var k in obj)
{
    console.log(k)
};
// No Output
```

Using Square Brackets

```js
obj = {["__proto__"]: "Hello"}
for (var k in obj)
{
    console.log(k)
};
// Output:
// __proto__
```

I understand that using the square brackets [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), but I don't understand why one would be enumerable and another would not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers). Computed property names of `__proto__` are *specifically excluded* from the `isProtoSetter` check, whereas normal string values of `__proto__` are permitted:

> 3. If propKey is the String value `__proto__` **and if IsComputedPropertyKey(PropertyName) is false**, then

> a. Let isProtoSetter be true.

> 4. Else,

> a. Let isProtoSetter be false.

The `isProtoSetter` flag, when true, indicates that the created object should have an internal prototype of the value paired with that key. The `__proto__` for the standard internal prototype of an object is not enumerable - it exists on `Object.prototype`:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__'));
```

When false, it's equivalent to having a *plain property* which is named `__proto__`, and plain properties in object initializers become enumerable.

Comment: One of the cases were a Note in the spec would be nice on the "why?!" ... probably "backwards compability"

Comment: I used `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor({["__proto__"]: "hello"}, '__proto__'));` to confirm this. It did indeed show that it is enumerable. While `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__'));` is not